# Jenkins groovy script - git command execution

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I've been trying to retrieve number of commits to use them as a number. The working command that i know of is: "git rev-list develop.. --count". Thats the number I try to get.
I want to assign it to variable and use it in some other line to introduce version, so my lines in groovy look like this.
Assignment:

```
       def commitCount = "git rev-list develop.. --count".execute()
```

Basically the Jenkins throws error at me that looks like this:

**"Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod"**

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`def out = sh(script: 'rev-list develop.. --count', returnStdout: true).trim()`

Comment: "Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node"